# PHP send object from script to script

Tags: php, object

I have a PHP webpage containing several php scripts. In the first script I create an object, which is needed by all scripts. In general I want to avoid globals, so how can I send an object from one script to another script?

My first point of thought was to use `$_SERVER['object']=$myobject`. But I realized that this is not working.
So I'm looking for another solution. 
In the past years I used `PHP_SELF`, but that was used in forms. In this case I do not have any forms and this object is created before a session is started and will be uses also outside sessions. Is there another option?

Comment: You can put the object in a session?

Comment: As I have written, the object is created before a session is started. This object is used also outside of sessions.

Comment: PHP does not share contexts from different requests so you can't pass objects or anything else between requests. What you can do though is to put all required data to reconstruct those objects in session or in GET parameters (redirects). You can also serialize objects and pass them through mentioned channels, but I don't recommend such approach.

Comment: Then relocate the session start?

Comment: Try with serialize and unserialize object

Comment: PHP is, essentially, stateless. Either construct the object whenever you need it, or store it in a session. If it's an instance of `PDO` or some other _non-serializable_ class, then forget about it. It can't be done. If it's just any old object, then using a session is the best way to do this type of thing. It really doesn matter if you want to use this object outside of a session. A session is just a storage tool

Comment: PHP doesn't have "application-level" objects like eg IIS/ASP does.  One idea is to serialize the object and write it to a file when you are done with it, and read/unserialize it when you need it (essentially how sessions are handled).  However if two object instances are active at the same time you will run into some clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you create a page , call it `Shared.php` or whatever , create the object inside it , and use `require("Shared.php");` in each of the needed scripts ? require will include this object defined in `Shared.php`

Comment: Do the obejct will be updated if script 1 used it before script 2 use it? What I mean script one updates $vara = 1, so script 2 is then able to see if $vara ==1?

Comment: Yes, your object will keep it's state.. As long as nothing changes in `Shared.php` for Script 1 and Script 2.

Comment: @IrgendwPointer no it won't keep its state without rewriting shared.php each time.

Comment: Does it keep the state or not? Two different opinions. Script a.php is calling shared.php and changes the variables, is Script b.php able to see the changed values in shared.php or not?